# Proving the parabola equation in complex form

Tags: complex-analysis, conic-sections

I wish to show that the following expression is a parabola:
$$(a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z)^2=2(b\bar{z}+\bar{b}z)+c$$
with $a,b,c$ complex numbers.
Whenever I face such an expression, I usually try to use $z=x+yi$ and try to get to the Cartesian form of whatever region it is. However in this case, after expanding the quadratic term:

$$a^2\bar{z}^2+2|a|^2|z|^2+\bar{a}^2z^2=2(b\bar{z}+\bar{b}z)+c$$
I don't see how replacing $z$ by $z=x+yi$ would help me proceed in any way. any hints?

Comment: Try to prove that there're real number $u_a, v_a$ so that $a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z=u_ax+v_ay$

Comment: To expand the tiniest bit on the prior comment, you have the right idea expressing $z$ as $x+iy$. Now expand $a$ as $b+ id$ and expand $a \bar z + \bar a z$

Comment: $c$ must be a real number, because the other terms are.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any complex numbers $u, v$, the sum of "cross-conjugate product pairs" is twice the real part of one cross-conjugate product, i.e.

$$u\bar{v}+v\bar{u}=2\Re(u\bar{v})=2\Re (\bar{u}v)$$

Let $a=p+iq$ and $b=m+in$.

Hence $$a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z=2\Re (\bar{a}z)=2\Re((p-iq)(x+iy))=px+qy\\
b\bar{z}+\bar{b}z=2\Re (\bar{b}z)=2\Re((m-in)(x+iy))=mx+ny$$

Given equation:

$$\begin{align}
(a\bar{z}+\bar{a}z)^2&=2(b\bar{z}+\bar{b}z)+c\\
(px+qy)^2&=2(mx+ny)+c\\
(px+qy)^2-2mx-2ny-c&=0\end{align}$$
which is the general equation for a parabola in the form
$$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

See also the wiki entry on [Conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form).